# ptrace %edx for sys_open inconsistent

Tags: linux, x86, system-calls, ptrace

I am trying to get the filename from the sys_open system call using ptrace. I get the filepath pointer, and I am able to get the correct data from that address, however, I need a way to know how much data to get, ie the length of the filename. I thought this value was supposed to be in edx, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Any thoughts?

```
        orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
        if(orig_eax == __NR_open){
            ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
            if(regs.eax > 0){                    
                filepath = (char *)calloc((regs.edx+1), sizeof(char));
                getdata(child, regs.ebx, filepath, regs.edx);

                printf("Open eax %ld ebx %ld ecx %ld filepath %s\n",regs.eax, regs.ebx, regs.ecx, filepath);

                free(filepath);
            }
        }
```

Sample output:

```
Open eax 3 ebx 2953895 edx 438 filepath /etc/localtime
Open eax 3 ebx 143028320 edx 384 filepath /var/log/vsftpd.log
Open eax 4 ebx 2957879 edx 438 filepath /etc/nsswitch.conf
Segmentation Fault
```

Just the edx:

```
edx 438
edx 384
edx 438
//seg fault here
edx -1217013808
edx 0
edx 143035796
edx 0
edx 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always like to check the [Linux System Call Table](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html) for situations like this, and then [this page](http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#open) for more details.

The fact is that for **sys_open**, `%edx` doesn't store the length of the filename. It stores *file permissions*.

The only way to know the length of the filename is *after* you retrieve the filename and pass it to **strlen()**, which will return the size of the string.

Comment: @karlphillip, The second link you gave is amazing. I have been looking for something like that all morning. I understand the strlen however, could you explain how I retrieve the filename to being with? How do I know how many times to call POKEDATA?

Comment: Great! It's also important for us that you review the answers and accept the one that solved your problem. Good luck.

Comment: sorry @karlphillip, just modified my comment. Could you take another look?

Comment: I'll be glad to do it in another thread because this one ha been answered already, and your new question justifies creating a new thread. Just so you do it right next time, where's POKEDATA on your code? I don't know what you mean by that. You can ask as many question as you would like. But don't hijack on your own thread, ok?

Comment: By the way, I found this tutorial quite clarifying: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100?page=0,0

Comment: @karlphillip, your point is well taken. I have been following that tutorial, which is actually where I get the getdata function from. I will add a new question, and send you a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @karlphillip: I am facing a similar problem which i posted it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799373/how-does-strace-read-the-file-name-of-system-call-sys-open] 
Can you take a look??