# How does strace read the file name of system call sys_open?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I am writing a program which uses Ptrace and does the following:

- It reads the current eax and checks if the system call is sys_open.
- If it is then i need to know what are the arguments that are passed.

  > int sys_open(const char * filename, const int mode, const int mask)

So eax = 5 implies it is a open system call
I came to know ebx has the address of the file location from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769350/system-call-tracing-using-ptrace)
But how do I knows the length of the file name so I can read the contents in that location?
I came across the following questions which address the same 
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489306/ptrace-edx-for-sys-open-inconsistent) 
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786648/using-ptrace-to-track-the-location-of-files-being-opened) (This one is mine only!)
But I still didn't get a solution to my problem. :( as both the answers were not clear. 
I am still getting a segmentation fault when I try the approach in the Question-1
You can check my code [here](http://pastie.org/3639720)
So Now I really was wondering how does strace extract these values so beautifully :(

Comment: If you're willing to dig a bit into the code, you can look it up yourself at http://strace.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=strace/strace;a=tree -- grepping `sys_open` might be a good start.

Comment: Did you study carefully the source code of `strace`? Did you try `strace strace true` ?

Comment: I am getting some compilation errors when I try compiling your code. http://ideone.com/SQie4. I think you need to paste the code for `helper.h` too

Comment: @che: [http://pastie.org/3639780] This has my helper.h which actually has the headers. Sorry for forgetting it :(

Comment: I didnt try strace strace true. Wait Ill google for it

Comment: @PavanManjunath: I pasted the helper.h too. Sorry fr forgetting it before :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, `sys_open()` doesn't receive the size of the filename as parameter. However, the standard says that a literal string must end with a `\0` character. This is good news, because now we can do a simple loop iterating over the characters of the string, and when we find a `\0` (NULL) character we know we've reached the end of it.

That's the standard procedure, that's how [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) does it, and also how [strace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/files/strace/) does it!

**C** example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* filename = "/etc/somefile";

    int fname_length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; filename[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        fname_length++;
    }

    printf("Found %d chars in: %s\n", fname_length, filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Back to your task at hand, you must access the address of `filename` and perform the procedure I just described. This is something you will have to do, and there's no other way.